# Getting information from DialogFragment using onDismiss()

Tags: android, dialog, android-dialogfragment

I am working on an app and I am using a custom dialog which extends DialogFragment. This dialog will contain certain field that I want to pass to the parent activity. I tried implementing OnDismissListener but the parameter is a Dialog Interface.

Any Idea?

parent Activity:

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            BreakCreator mDialog = new BreakCreator();
            mDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "start break Creator");

        }
    });
```

listener:

```
@Override
public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
    Log.d("debug", "in onDismiss");
        BreakCreator mBreakCreator = BreakCreator.class.cast(dialog);// This MIGHT not work
    //TODO cast and shit

        if(!mBreakCreator.isCancelled() ){
            int startMinute = mBreakCreator.getStartMinute();
            int startHour = mBreakCreator.getStartHour();
            int endMinute = mBreakCreator.getEndMinute();
            int endHour = mBreakCreator.getEndHour();
            String day = mBreakCreator.getDay();

            Break mBreak = new Break(new ultramirinc.champs_mood.Time(startHour, startMinute),
                    new ultramirinc.champs_mood.Time(endHour, endMinute), day);
            breakList.add(mBreak);
            Log.d("created", "break added");
            recyclerView.invalidate();

        }else{
            Log.d("debug", "is not cancelled");
    }
}
```

Dialog Class:

```
public void onDismiss(final DialogInterface dialog) {
    super.onDismiss(dialog);
    final Activity activity = getActivity();
    if (activity instanceof DialogInterface.OnDismissListener) {
        ((DialogInterface.OnDismissListener) activity).onDismiss(dialog);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no clue how to get the information since I cannot cast DialogInterface into DialogFragment

Comment: Read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/) and [this](https://www.google.se/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=15&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiA7uXDoaLTAhWDjiwKHVnYBRAQFghxMA4&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.vogella.com%2Ftutorials%2FDesignPatternObserver%2Farticle.html&usg=AFQjCNGGgYexZpJrbf-LiedTH0yRc675rQ&sig2=OUgdD_VLKZWmUpfUsS_sLA)

Comment: I get the idea of adding a listener to an object, yet my custom DialogFragment doesn't seem to have a method: setOnDismissListener

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a custom listener, below is an example on how this could be implemented. This is also explained in the [Android Developer Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#PassingEvents).

```
public class CustomDialog extends DialogFragment {

   public interface CustomListener{
      void onMyCustomAction(CustomObject co);
   }

   private CustomListener mListener;

   public void setMyCustomListener(CustomListener listener){
     mListener = listener;
   }

   @Override
   public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      ...
      Code to create dialog 
      ...
   }

   @Override
   public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
       if(mListener != null){
          CustomObject o = new CustomObject();
          mListener.onMyCustomAction(o);
       }
       super.onDismiss();
   }
}
```

And when the custom dialog is created, set the listener.

```
CustomDialog awesomeDialog = new CustomDialog();
awesomeDialog.setMyCustomListener(new CustomDialog.CustomListener() {
  @Override
  public void onMyCustomAction(CustomObject o){
     Log.i("TAG",o.toString());
  }
});
```